# Load p:selectCheckboxMenu items on click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using the PrimeFaces `inplace` component and I want to load elements inside a `selectCheckboxMenu` when the user clicks on the component. How can I achieve that?

PS: I used the `dynamic` attribute but it seems it doesn't help.

```html
<p:inplace label="Values" effectSpeed="fast">
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu
                     dynamic="true"
                     multiple="true"
                     updateLabel="true"
                     value="#{referential.values}"
                     label="Values">
                                 
        <f:selectItems value="#{segmentParamsView.calculateValues(referential)}"
                       var="value"
                       itemLabel="#{value}"
                       itemValue="#{value}"/>
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
</p:inplace>
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to resolve? What do you mean by "but it doesn't help"?

Comment: i want to load elements in selectCheckboxMenu just when the user wants to update by clicking on the inplace component... i want to improve performances